# Go fiber not running on localhost

Tags: go, go-fiber

I am using this web framework for go: https://github.com/gofiber/fiber

I want to run the basic example they gave called ["hello world"](https://github.com/gofiber/recipes/blob/master/hello-world/main.go)

I copied the code and put it in a file called `main.go`

```golang
// ⚡️ Fiber is an Express inspired web framework written in Go with ☕️
//  Github Repository: https://github.com/gofiber/fiber
//  API Documentation: https://docs.gofiber.io

package main

import (
    "log"

    "github.com/gofiber/fiber"
)

func main() {
    // Fiber instance
    app := fiber.New()

    // Routes
    app.Get("/", hello)

    // Start server
    log.Fatal(app.Listen(3000))
}

// Handler
func hello(c *fiber.Ctx) {
    c.Send("Hello, World !")
}
```

Before I ran the script I also made sure to install the framework by using `go get -u github.com/gofiber/fiber`.

Then running `go run main.go` the file runs but it doesn't run on my local host and tells me it is running on `HOST[::]`

How can I make it so it runs on `localhost` rather than `HOST[::]`. I tried to see if it was on my localhost and it is not there at all.

[image: Here is the output I get]

Comment: Turn off your vpn too!!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [fiber godoc reference](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/gofiber/fiber?tab=doc#App.Listen):

> func (*App) Listen ¶
> func (app *App) Listen(address interface{}, tlsconfig ...*tls.Config) error
> Listen serves HTTP requests from the given addr or port. You can pass an optional *tls.Config to enable TLS.
>
> - app.Listen(8080) - app.Listen("8080") - app.Listen(":8080") - app.Listen("127.0.0.1:8080")

You can do:

```
app.Listen("localhost:3000")
```

Answer (score 1):

The argument of app.Listen function must be an string and if u want define the port is mandatory the two points:

```
log.Fatal(app.Listen(":3000"))
```

Answer (score 0):

There is probably something else running on port 3000. Switch to another port.

```
app.Listen(8000)
```